# Regex to replace portions of string based on position

Tags: jquery, regex, string, replace, position

Given the following string:

```
matrix(1.5, 0, 0, 2, 160, 160)
```

I'd like to replace the first and fourth values – no matter what they are – with `1`, so I'd have:

```
matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 160, 160)
```

If the first and fourth values happen to be the same, I can replace them easily like this:

```
.replace(/1\.5/g, "1")
```

But that just matches on the number, not the position, so it doesn't work if the first and fourth values aren't identical. I want to replace *any* values at both of those positions with `1`.

Comment: its me or you changed fouth number in example :/

Comment: You're right, I meant first and fourth, not first and third. Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex:

```
.replace(/[\d.]+(?=(?:, [\d.]+){5}|(?:, [\d.]+){2}\))/g, "1")
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/kY0cZ2)

It will basically match a digit (with periods if any) only if there are 5 or 2 more digits ahead of it until a closing paren.

Comment: This is the solution for question `"How can I replace third value from the end and anywhere in the middle with five values in front?"` Maybe the OP implied that with an example string. But he did assert left to right positions.

Answer (score 1):

this pattern `[\d.]+((,[\s*\d.]+){2},\s*)[\d.]+` will replace 1st and fourth argument regardless of the amount of remaining arguments.
Replace with `1$11`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cQ9xZ7)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that doesn't require any knowledge of the current argument type:

```
.replace(/\(([^,]*),\s*([^,]*),\s*([^,]*),\s*([^,]*),\s*(.*?)\)/, "(1, $2, $3, 1, $5)");
```

This works by matching from the opening paren to the closing paren and capturing each argument in a separate capturing group (except that all remaining arguments are captured in group 5).  This is slightly longer than some of the other alternatives but it makes for a very readable replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Reading left to right, you can always section off the segments you want to replace. Doesn't matter if its 1 or 99:

```
 #  (\(\s*)[^,]*((?:,[^,]*){2},\s*)[^,]*
 #  Replacement =  $1 + '1' + $2 + '1' 

 ( \( \s* )              # (1), Preamble
 [^,]*                   # 1st value
 (                       # (2), middle 

      (?: , [^,]* ){2}
      , \s* 
 )
 [^,]*                   # 4th value
```